Dickey-Fuller Unit Root test, Deterministic Terms
I'm learning about unit root tests and i'm trying to implement these tests in python. I have some doubts about the theory underlying the deterministic terms inside the regression.
Some textbooks ( Time Series Analysis Forecasting and Control by Box e Jenkins or Econometrics by Hayashi ) derives tests ( including no deterministic terms, a costant or a costant + linear trend ) in this way:
$Y_t = D T_t + X_t$   where DT is the deterministic term and X is the stochastic process, for semplicity suppose:
$X_t = \rho X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$  where $\epsilon$ is a i.i.d. process with zero mean and $\sigma^2$ variance
Rearranging the formula, with $DT_t = \alpha + \beta t$ we obtain:
$Y_t - \rho Y_{t-1} = \alpha (1 - \rho ) + \beta \rho + (1-\rho) \beta t + \epsilon_t$
So the regression model is in the form:
$Y_t = \rho Y_{t-1} + \alpha_* + \beta_* t + \epsilon_t$ where $\alpha_* = \alpha (1 - \rho ) + \beta \rho$ and $\beta_* = (1-\rho) \beta$
So it includes a costant + linear term.
We could also subtract $Y_{t-1}$ from both side and obtain:
$\Delta Y_t = \phi Y_{t-1} + \alpha_* + \beta_* t + \epsilon_t$, with $\phi = \rho - 1$
and the regression models contains a costant + linear trend again.
Under the Null Hypothesis that the process has a unit root ($\rho = 1$ or $\phi = 0$) then $\beta_* = 0 , \alpha_* = \beta$ , so
$\Delta Y_t = \beta + \epsilon_t$
If we reject the Null Hypothesis then, $\rho < 1,  \beta_* \neq 0$  and $Y_t = \rho Y_{t-1} + \alpha_* + \beta_* t + \epsilon_t$
This makes sense to me because if I have a time series with a linear term and i want to test the hypothesis that this linear term comes from a unit root or a deterministic linear term.
So if i want to test if a time series is a random walk with drift or is trend-stationary, i would include a costant + linear term inside the regression, assuming the restriction for $\beta_* = 0$
under the null hypothesis.
Other textbooks and the wikipedia page for Dickey-Fuller test start by discussing the three form of the Dickey-Fuller test:
$\Delta Y_t = \phi Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$
$\Delta Y_t = \alpha + \phi Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$
$\Delta Y_t = \alpha + \beta t + \phi Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$
These models don't make any restriction under the null hypothesis.
So if i wanted to test the same time series with a deterministic linear term ( that i don't know if it comes from a unit root processes or a deterministic linear term), under null hypothesis of a unit root i would have to choose the second model just with a costant. Suppose that this test doesn't reject the unit root hypothesis so i would accept the fact that my time series has a unit root.
My concern is that the choosen regression model wouldn't account for a possible linear deterministic term, in fact if we reject the null hypothesis
$\Delta Y_t = \alpha + \phi Y_{t-1}$ with $\phi < 0$ is equal to $Y_t = \alpha + (1+\phi)Y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$. So it is a stationary process ( and obviously it can't match with my time series with a trend! )
So i think i would also test the third regression model, hoping to not reject the null hypothesis of a unit root, otherwise it would mean that the third regression model under the alternative hypothesis is
$Y_t = \alpha + \beta t + (1+\phi) Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ with $\phi < 0$ implying stationary around a deterministic linear trend. So now I can't accept neither if the time series is a unit root with a drift term, neither a stationary process around a linear deterministic term, because the first test accept the null hypothesis of a unit root with a drift term, the second test reject the null hypothesis of a unit root with a drift and a linear term.
I'm trying to read the documentation of statsmodel package in python and other R package URCA. They let me insert a costant, a costant + linear deterministic trend or none deterministic term in the regression model( in statsmodel the let me insert also a quadratic deterministic term) but they don't talk about any restrictions in the deterministic parameter under the Unit Root Null Hypothesis. So i think they are in the second type of regression model i 've described above.
Are my arguments correct?
What is the difference between these 2 approaches for unit root? does incorporating a costant with restriction in the regression model affect the distribution of the test statistics?
Moving on to software for testing unit roots, both python statsmodels and R URCA package seems to be without any restrictions on the deterministic parameters.
MatLab documentation is the only software i found which explicits the difference between the model under the Null Hypothesis and the model under the Alternative Hypothesis:

Are these models different or am i misunderstanding something?
Thank you for any answers and for helping me!

I am struggling to understand exactly this, let me know if you figured it out :)

AFAICS the 3rd equation is wrong (1−ρ)βt should be βt - ρβ(t-1). ρ is with lag operation ρ(L) and we need to apply (1-ρ(L)) to the trend timeseries t, i.e. differencing the trend variable. Similarly, ΔYt=α+ϕYt−1 adds alpha in each period, i.e. has a trend term or, more precisely, a constant drift. So the issue is whether it's a deterministic trend (Y is trend stationary) versus stochastic trend (unit root with drift). (I don't remember the other details.)
